# Understanding inheritance in the context of generics wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I came across following image on oracle docs explaining inheritance in the context of generics:

[image]

**Doubts**

1. I know `List<Integer>` is not a sub type of `List<Number>`, but then how exactly `List<Number>` is a sub type of `List<? extends Number>`? Is it just how it is done by java designers? Is there any more details to it, possibly low level?
2. How `List<Number>` is sub type of `List<? extends Number>`?

Comment: "but then how exactly `List<? extends Number>` is a sub type of `List<? extends Number>`?" That's the same type.

Comment: `List<? extends T>` means "everything in the list can be cast to T". `List<T>` means "everything in the list can be cast to T, *and* the list will accept instances of T". Hopefully it's then obvious why a `List<T>` is also a `List<? extends T>`.

Comment: This is subtyping, not inheritance.

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry I incorrectly asked it. I was to ask "how exactly `List<Number>` is a sub type of `List<? extends Number>`?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but then how exactly `List<? extends Number>` is a sub type of `List<? extends Number>`?

They are the same type! Did you mean:

> but then how exactly `List<? extends Integer>` is a sub type of `List<? extends Number>`?

`List<T>` means "a list of `T`s", whereas `List<? extends T>` means "a list of some unknown type, but I know it's a subclass of `T`". In other words, what `List<Number>` is is "set in stone", whereas `List<? extends Number>` can be one of many things: `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>`, `List<Number>` and so on. We don't know.

If you have understood this nuance, you shouldn't find the fact that you can't add `Integer`s to a `List<? extends Number>` surprising. Why? Because the `List<? extends Number>` could very well be a `List<Double>`. You can't add `Integer`s to `List<Double>`, can you?

Now the answer to the question should be clear, `List<? extends Integer>` could be a list of any subclass of `Integer`, whereas `List<? extends Number>` could be a list of any subclass of `Number`. Since, `Integer` extends `Number`, any list of a subclass of `Integer` must also be a list of a subclass of `Number`.

But note that a list of `Integer` is not a list of `Number`, since you can't add `Double`s to a list of `Integer`, but you can to a list of `Number`.

> How `List<Number>` is sub type of `List<? extends Number>`?

This is kind of "by definition" of the `<? extends T>` syntax. There is no reason not to allow `<T>` itself. And I do agree `extends` is misleading here.

---

Also note that this is not really "inheritance". All the types involved here are really just the same JVM type `List`, which is also an interface. Inheritance happens between classes. Your wording in the question body - "subtype" - is more appropriate.

Comment: your last two paragraphs is what all I needed!

Comment: I tried `List<? extends Number> l5 = new ArrayList<Number>();  l5.add((Number) new Integer(5));`. It was giving error. I am guessing, then what we can add to `l5`?

Comment: @anir You can't add anything. You can only get stuff (`Number`s, to be specific) out of `l5`. This is known as "[Producers Extend, Consumer Super (PECS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)".

Comment: What do you mean by we cannot add anything? No value / element can be added to `l5`!!?? But then why and how it makes sense to have such a list? Also I earlier read that we can only add `null` to `List<?>` but not any element. I just checked we can also add only `null` to `l5`. Again why so & how it makes sense to have such collection. Also does this apply to all `List<#>` where `#` is "? with super or extend"? May be reading PECS link will explain?

Comment: @anir It would be useful if you don't intend to add anything to it :) Obviously, you wouldn't do `new List<? extends Number>()` (it's illegal anyway) because such a list is useless. However, a method could accept such a list as a parameter if it doesn't need to add to the list. This makes the method more flexible as more types of lists are acceptable. More suggested reading in addition to PECS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124391/java-8-comparator-comparing-static-function/49124661#49124661

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208355/discussion-between-sweeper-and-anir).

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same question as you.

It can be understood using set theory:

1. `List<? extends Number>` contains `List<Number>`, `List<Byte>`, `List<Double>`, `List<Float>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<Short>`, `List<Long>`. You can think of `List<? extends Number>` as a set of 7 elements listed before. When two non-empty sets A and B are equal. It is not wrong to state that A is a subset of B and B is a subset of A.
2. `List<? extends Number>` contains `List<Number>` as its element. Therefore, `List<Number>` is a sub-type of `List<? extends Number>`.

Hope this will help!