# Scala - covariant type in mutable collections

Tags: scala, immutability, covariance, mutability, invariance

I am new in Scala world and now I am reading the book called "Scala in Action" (by Nilanjan Raychaudhuri), namely the part called "Mutable object need to be invariant" on page 97 and I don't understand the following part which is taken directly from the mentioned book.

---

Assume ListBuffer is covariant and the following code snippet works without any compilation problem:

```
scala> val mxs: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer("pants")
mxs: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] =
ListBuffer(pants)
scala> val everything: ListBuffer[Any] = mxs
scala> everything += 1
res4: everything.type = ListBuffer(1, pants)
```

Can you spot the problem? Because everything is of the type Any, you can store an
integer value into a collection of strings. This is a disaster waiting to happen. To avoid these kinds of problems, it’s always a
good idea to make mutable objects invariant.

---

I would have the following questions..

1) What type of `everything` is in reality? `String` or `Any`? The declaration is "`val everything: ListBuffer[Any]`" and hence I would expect `Any` and because everything should be type of `Any` then I don't see any problems to have `Integer` and `String` in one `ListBuffer[Any]`. How can I store integer value into collection of strings how they write??? Why disaster??? Why should I use List (which is immutable) instead of ListBuffer (which is mutable)? I see no difference. I found a lot of answers that mutably collections should have type invariant and that immutable collections should have covariant type but why?

2) What does the last part "`res4: everything.type = ListBuffer(1, pants)`" mean? What does "everything.type" mean? I guess that `everything` does not have any method/function or variable called `type`.. Why is there no ListBuffer[Any] or ListBuffer[String]?

Thanks a lot,

Andrew

Comment: Hi! If I have time later, I can attempt to write a full answer (unless someone beats me to it or closes the question as duplicate). But in the meantime, sounds like [this article](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/variance-in-java-and-scala-63af925d21dc) could help you with some concepts.

Answer (score 5):

**1** This doesn't look like a single question, so I have to subdivide it further:

1. "In reality" `everything` is `ListBuffer[_]`, with erased parameter type. Depending on the JVM, it holds either 32 or 64 bit references to some objects. The types `ListBuffer[String]` and `ListBuffer[Any]` is what the compiler knows about it at compile time. If it "knows" two contradictory things, then it's obviously very bad.
2. *"I don't see any problems to have Integer and String in
   one ListBuffer[Any]"*. There is no problem to have `Int` and `String` in `ListBuffer[Any]`, because `ListBuffer` is invariant. However, in your hypothetical example, `ListBuffer` is covariant, so you are storing an `Int` in a `ListBuffer[String]`. If someone later gets an `Int` from a `ListBuffer[String]`, and tries to interpret it as `String`, then it's obviously very bad.
3. *"How can I store integer value into collection
   of strings how they write?"* Why would you want to do something that is obviously very bad, as explained above?
4. *"Why disaster???"* It wouldn't be a major disaster. Java has been living with covariant arrays forever. It's does not lead to cataclysms, it's just bad and annoying.
5. *"Why should I use List (which is immutable) instead of ListBuffer (which is mutable)?"* There is no absolute imperative that tells you to always use `List` and to never use `ListBuffer`. Use both when it is appropriate. In 99.999% of cases, `List` is of course more appropriate, because you use `List`s to represent data way more often than you design complicated algorithms that require local mutable state of a `ListBuffer`.
6. *"I found a lot of answers that mutably collections
   should have type invariant and that immutable collections should
   have covariant type but why?"*. This is wrong, you are over-simplifying. For example, intensional immutable sets should be neither covariant, nor invariant, but *contravariant*. You should use covariance, contravariance, and invariance when it's appropriate. [This little silly illustration has proven unreasonably effective for explaining the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48858344/2707792), maybe you too find it useful.

**2** This is a [singleton type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#singleton-types), just like in the following example:

```
scala> val x = "hello"
x: String = hello

scala> val y: x.type = x
y: x.type = hello
```

Here is a [longer discussion about the motivation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/42.type.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most of what @Andrey is saying I would just add that covariance and contravariance belong exclusively to immutable structures, the exercisce that the books proposes is just a example so people can understand but it is not possible to implement a mutable structure that is covariant, you won't be able to make it compile.
As an exercise you could try to implement a `MutableList[+A]`, you'll find out that there is not way to do this without tricking the compiler putting `asInstanceOf` everywhere

Comment: Saying that it is "not possible to implement a mutable structure that is covariant" is again an over-simplification. Does for example a mutable tuple that can hold two values `a1` and `a2` of same type `A`, and has a mutating method `swap(): Unit` count as a "mutable structure"? It certainly is a data structure (not a very useful one, but still), and it is certainly mutable (even though it has only `swap`, no setters). There would be no problem implementing it as covariant. This whole "immutable = covariant" "mutable = invariant" story is not a rule, it's a vague heuristic at best...

Comment: But I have to agree: "Just try to implement it, you will see that you are forced to put `asInstanceOf` on everything" is a good hint overall. One can't understand it until one actually tries to rebuild a little toy collection-library on your own.

Comment: I don't think that a mutable Tuple can be implemented as covariant, if you know how to do it I would be very interested in see it

Comment: of course using asInstanceOf is not acceptable for a valid implementation

Comment: Indentation will probably break, but here you go: `class T[+A](a1: A, a2: A) {
  private[this] var v1: A = a1
  private[this] var v2: A = a2
  def _1: A = v1
  def _2: A = v2
  def swap(): Unit = {
    val temp = v2
    v2 = v1
    v1 = temp
  }
}

val t1: T[String] = new T("hello", "world")
val t2: T[Any] = t1 // is ok, covariant

println(t2._1)
t1.swap()
println(t2._1) // obviously mutable` The only thing that one might object is that "mutable" is a [red herring](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle) and used in the sense of "not immutable".

Comment: well, you didn't implement any covariant operation... that's where you will have problems, but if it is only about T[A] <: T[Any] then it's true that it can be done, but no functionality like setting _2 can be implemented

Comment: but I see your point that is technically possible for a very restricted structures

Comment: "Very restricted" is difficult to quantify. My point is rather: covariance/invariance is more or less orthogonal to any other property like mutability/immutability, growability, or whatever. Neither property strictly implies the other. E.g. immutability and covariance, while being positively correlated in most libraries, do not imply each other, one can always come up with a somewhat contrived, but valid counterexample.

Comment: I understand, my point was that in Scala it is not possible to write any covariant mutable structure that have covariant operations, so you would be restricted to a few mutate operations like `swap` that don't take an A as paramter, but if you try to implement `set_2` you won't be able.