# Why immutable.Map's value type is covariant while mutable's one is not

Tags: scala

just read Scala collection implementation and noticed a subtile difference:

- **immutable HashMap** : `class HashMap[A, +B]()`
- **mutable HashMap** : `class HashMap[A, B]()`

Could you please explain me why the immutable's value type is covariant while the mutable's one is not ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49410925/736957

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the mutable map were covariant, it would be possible to do something like this:

```
val m1: mutable.Map[String, Int] = mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]
val m2: mutable.Map[String, Any] = m1
m2 += ("foo" -> "bar")
m1("foo") // returns "bar" out of a Map[String, Int]???
```

Answer (score 3):

The mutable `HashMap` has methods taking `B` as argument, e.g. `def update(key: A, value: B): Unit`. Presence of such methods means `B` can't be covariant, or you could write

```
val map: mutable.HashMap[Int, AnyRef] = mutable.HashMap.empty[Int, String]
map.update(0, new AnyRef) // call update(Int, AnyRef) where (Int, String) is expected
```

The immutable one doesn't.