# What is a real life example of generic <? super T>?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, super

I understand that `<? super T>` represents any super class of `T` (parent class of `T` of any level). But I really struggle to imagine any real life example for this generic bound wildcard.

I understand what `<? super T>` means and I have seen this method:

```
public class Collections {
  public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
      for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++)
        dest.set(i, src.get(i));
  }
}
```

I am looking for an example of *real life use case* where this construction can be used and not for an explanation of what it is.

Comment: this should give you an idea of when to use super: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: this is NOT a duplicate, a very valid question

Comment: i also dont think its a duplicate, he is asking for concrete situations, not the principle behind

Comment: This is the start of the answer that I was about to write when this one was closed: I agree to some extent with the close-voters: The answer *could* be derived, with some diligence, from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super . However, this question (as well as the answers here) focus on the technical principle. A simple, **realistic** example of where it makes sense to use `? super T` could be helpful.

Comment: Don't think this should have been closed as a duplicate, since the author is asking for real-world models of OOP, rather than in-depth explanations of how inheritance works in Java.

Comment: Check out the [Variance section of Kotlin tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance). It gives a couple of examples and why Kotlin decided to use `in`/`out` instead of  `? super T` and `? extends T`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is T bounded by Object in the Collections.max() signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488357/why-is-t-bounded-by-object-in-the-collections-max-signature)

Comment: I give an extensive discussion of co-, contra-, and invariance in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303536/2988 The question is framed as a Scala question, but my answer discusses variance in full generality without referencing any particular language.

Comment: By the way, it is quite normal to be confused by this. Subtyping is easy. Parametric Polymorphism (Generics) is easy. Somehow, when you mix the two, everybody gets confused. Eiffel, a language that is *specifically designed* as a "safe" programming language, originally got this wrong, and Bertrand Meyer is a *very* smart guy. Java arrays are completely broken in this respect. Even worse: C♯ arrays, even though the designers had the benefit of learning from Java, are completely broken. Generics in Dart are *deliberately* broken to make them easier to understand.

Comment: Note: the real-life examples are at the end of the answer I mentioned in my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185915/what-is-a-real-life-example-of-generic-super-t#comment91336404_52185915).

Comment: Isn't this example here a real life use case?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The easiest example I can think of is:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    list.sort(null);
}
```

taken from the same `Collections`. This way a `Dog` can implement `Comparable<Animal>` and if `Animal` already implements that, `Dog` does not have to do anything.

**EDIT for a real example:**

After some email ping-pongs, I am allowed to present a real example from my work-place (yay!).

We have an interface called `Sink` (it does not matter what it does), the idea is that is *accumulates* things. The declaration is pretty trivial (simplified):

```
interface Sink<T> {
    void accumulate(T t);
}
```

Obviously there is a helper method that takes a `List` and drains it's elements to a `Sink` (it's a bit more complicated, but to make it simple):

```
public static <T> void drainToSink(List<T> collection, Sink<T> sink) {
    collection.forEach(sink::accumulate);
}
```

This is simple right? Well...

I can have a `List<String>`, but I want to drain it to a `Sink<Object>` - this is a fairly common thing to do for us; but this will fail:

```
Sink<Object> sink = null;
List<String> strings = List.of("abc");
drainToSink(strings, sink);
```

For this to work we need to change the declaration to:

```
public static <T> void drainToSink(List<T> collection, Sink<? super T> sink) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Kotlin [tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) uses `Source` as example... which is basically the dual of your `Sink` example.

Comment: Surely you could define it in the opposite way by making the list ? extends T?

Comment: @WeckarE. Not if the method is on the list itself.

Comment: @WeckarE. I could yes, but this would change the semantics a bit now I can't add anything to that `list`, it becomes a producer only; as said this is a simplified example...

Answer (score 15):

Suppose you have this class hierarchy:
Cat inherits from Mammal, which in turn inherits from Animal.

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
List<Mammal> mammals = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cat> cats = ...
```

These calls are valid:

```
Collections.copy(animals, mammals); // all mammals are animals
Collections.copy(mammals, cats);    // all cats are mammals
Collections.copy(animals, cats);    // all cats are animals
Collections.copy(cats, cats);       // all cats are cats
```

But these calls are *not* valid:

```
Collections.copy(mammals, animals); // not all animals are mammals
Collections.copy(cats, mammals);    // not all mammals are cats
Collections.copy(cats, animals);    // mot all animals are cats
```

So the method signature simply insures that you copy from a more specific (lower in the inheritance hierarchy) class to a more generic class (upper in the inheritance hierarchy), and not the other way round.

Comment: The `super` keyword isn't necessary for this to work, though. This signature would also have exposed identical behavior:

   `public static <T> void copy(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {`

Comment: @Nick Good catch. Why this signature then ? This question  should be raised to Java language designers. So far the only reason I found is that you can write code like:
`Collections.<Mammal>copy(animals, cats);` - but I don't know why someone would/should write code like this...

Answer (score 7):

For example, look into the [`Collections.addAll`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l5429) method implmenetation:

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (T element : elements)
        result |= c.add(element);
    return result;
}
```

Here, the elements can be inserted into any collection whose element type is a supertype of the type `T` of the element.

Without a lower bounded wildcard:

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c, T... elements) { ... }
```

the following would have been invalid:

```
List<Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.<Integer>addAll(nums , 1, 2, 3);
```

because the term `Collection<T>` is more restrictive than `Collection<? super T>`.

---

**Another example:**

[`Predicate<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) interface in Java, that uses a `<? super T>` wildcard in the following methods:

```
default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other);

default Predicate<T>  or(Predicate<? super T> other);
```

`<? super T>` allows to chain a wider range of different predicates, for example:

```
Predicate<String> p1 = s -> s.equals("P");
Predicate<Object> p2 = o -> o.equals("P");

p1.and(p2).test("P"); // which wouldn't be possible with a Predicate<T> as a parameter
```

Comment: I don't think this example is particularly compelling. If you leave out the explicit instantiation of the type variable, you're just as able to write `Collections.addAll(nums, 1, 2, 3)` with either method signature.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a method:

```
passToConsumer(Consumer<? super SubType> consumer)
```

then you call this method with any `Consumer` which can consume `SubType`:

```
passToConsumer(Consumer<SuperType> superTypeConsumer)
passToConsumer(Consumer<SubType> subTypeConsumer)
passToConsumer(Consumer<Object> rootConsumer)
```

---

For exmaple:

```
class Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{

    void putInto(List<? super Dog> list) {
        list.add(this);
    }
}
```

So I can put the `Dog` into `List<Animal>` or `List<Dog>`:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();

Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.putInto(dogs);  // OK
dog.putInto(animals);   // OK
```

---

If you change `putInto(List<? super Dog> list)` method to `putInto(List<Animal> list)`:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();

List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
dog.putInto(dogs);  // compile error, List<Dog> is not sub type of List<Animal>
```

or `putInto(List<Dog> list)`:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();

List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
dog.putInto(animals); // compile error, List<Animal> is not sub type of List<Dog>
```

Comment: whenever you say `Consumer` or `consume` this automatically falls into the `PECS` category, not saying this is bad though, good examples

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a webradio, so I had the class `MetaInformationObject`, which was the superclass for PLS and M3U playlists. I had a selection dialogue, so I had:

```
public class SelectMultipleStreamDialog <T extends MetaInformationObject>
public class M3UInfo extends MetaInformationObject
public class PLSInfo extends MetaInformationObject
```

This class had a method `public T getSelectedStream()`.
So the caller received a T which was of the concrete type (PLS or M3U), but needed to work on the superclass, so there was a list: `List<T super MetaInformationObject>`.  where the result was added.
Thats how a generic dialogue could handle the concrete implementations and the rest of the code could work on the superclass.
Hope that makes it a little more clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this simple example:

```
List<Number> nums = Arrays.asList(3, 1.2, 4L);
Comparator<Object> numbersByDouble = Comparator.comparing(Object::toString);
nums.sort(numbersByDouble);
```

Hopefully this is a somewhat compelling case: You could imagine wanting to sort the numbers for display purposes (for which the toString is a reasonable ordering), but `Number` is not itself Comparable.

This compiles because `integers::sort` takes a `Comparator<? super E>`. If it took just a `Comparator<E>` (where `E` in this case is `Number`), then the code would fail to compile because `Comparator<Object>` is not a subtype of `Comparator<Number>` (due to reasons that your question indicates you already understand, so I won't go into).

Answer (score 1):

Collections serve as a good example here.

As stated in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java), `List<? super T>` lets you create `List` that will hold elements of type, that are less derived than `T`, so it can hold elements that inherit from `T`, that are type of `T` and that `T` inherits from.

On the other hand, `List<? extends T>` lets you define a `List` that can hold only elements that inherit from `T` (in some cases not even of type `T`).

This is a good example:

```
public class Collections {
  public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
      for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++)
        dest.set(i, src.get(i));
  }
}
```

Here you want to project `List` of less derived type to `List` of less derived type.
Here `List<? super T>` assures us that all elements from `src` will be valid in the new collection.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) : [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have:

```
class T {}
class Decoder<T>
class Encoder<T>

byte[] encode(T object, Encoder<? super T> encoder);    // encode objects of type T
T decode(byte[] stream, Decoder<? extends T> decoder);  // decode a byte stream into a type T
```

And then:

```
class U extends T {}
Decoder<U> decoderOfU;
decode(stream, decoderOfU);     // you need something that can decode into T, I give you a decoder of U, you'll get U instances back

Encoder<Object> encoderOfObject;
encode(stream, encoderOfObject);// you need something that can encode T, I give you something that can encode all the way to java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score -1):

A few real life examples come to mind for this. The first one I like to bring up, is the idea of a real-world object being used for 'improvised' functionality. Imagine that you have a socket wrench:

```
public class SocketWrench <T extends Wrench>
```

The obvious purpose of a socket wrench it so be used as a `Wrench`. However, if you consider that a wrench could be used in a pinch to pound in a nail, you could have an inheritance hierarchy that looks like this:

```
public class SocketWrench <T extends Wrench>
public class Wrench extends Hammer
```

In this scenario, you would be able to call `socketWrench.pound(Nail nail = new FinishingNail())`, even though that would be considered an atypical use for a `SocketWrench`.

While all along, the `SocketWrench` would have access to be able to call methods like `applyTorque(100).withRotation("clockwise").withSocketSize(14)` if it's being used as a `SocketWrench` instead of just a `Wrench`, instead of a `Hammer`.

Comment: I don't find this very compelling: why would SocketWrench be a generic?

Comment: You can have all sorts socket wrench types: 1/4” drive, 1/2” drive, adjustable handle angle socket wrenches, torque wrenches, differing ratchet teeth counts, etc. But if you just needed a wrench that ratchets, you could use a generic SocketWrench instead of a specific 3/4” drive 32-tooth angled handle socket wrench.