# Type L is in contravariant position in type A => Either[L, B]

Tags: scala, types, variance, contravariance

I tried to write simple implementation of flatMap for Either

```
sealed trait Either[+L, +R] {
  def flatMap[B](f: R => Either[L, B]): Either[L, B] = this match {
    case Left(e) => Left(e)
    case Right(e) => f(e)
  }
}

final case class Right[+A, +B](right: B) extends Either[A, B]
final case class Left[+A, +B](left: A) extends Either[A, B]
```

and faced following problem:
covariant type L is in contravariant position in type f: R => Either[L, B] of value f, but why is it so? I thought that our type is in contravariant position when we take variant type as an argument for function and it has nothing to do with a type declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `R => Either[L, B]` as a "generalized value of type `L`" - it's not exactly the same thing as an `L`, but given an `R` it might *produce* an `L`. So, your `flatMap` "consumes generalized values of type `L`". At the same time, your variance declaration claims that `Either[+L, +R]` is covariant in `L`, therefore, an `Either[VerySpecial, R]` would have to be a special case of `Either[RatherGeneral, R]`. But this is impossible, because the `flatMap` that can consume only `VerySpecial` values would choke on a `RatherGeneral` input.

- In `Either[+L, +R]`, `L` is in covariant position (it ["produces"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812254/how-to-check-covariant-and-contravariant-position-of-an-element-in-the-function/48858344#48858344) `L`s, at least sometimes)
- In `R => Either[L, B]`, `L` is still in covariant position (because the function produces `Either[L, B]`, and `Either[L, B]` in turn produces `L`s, so the whole thing produces `L`s)
- In `(R => Either[L, B]) => Either[L, B]`, the first `L` appears in *contra*variant position, because the argument part is *consumed* by the method `flatMap`.

This is easily fixed with the standard lower-type-bounds trick:

```
sealed trait Either[+L, +R] {
  def flatMap[B, M >: L](f: R => Either[M, B]): Either[M, B] = this match {
    case Left(e) => Left(e)
    case Right(e) => f(e)
  }
}

final case class Right[+A, +B](right: B) extends Either[A, B]
final case class Left[+A, +B](left: A) extends Either[A, B]
```

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! But then why type R is not highlighted in R => Either[L, B]  with an error as its in contravariant position ( f consumes R which in turn consumed by flatMap)

Comment: @nicksigevsky Because `(R => X) => Y` should be thought of as a generalized value of type `R` [which is, indeed, a very general principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma#The_Yoneda_embedding). `R` is covariant in `(R => X) => Y`.

Comment: @nicksigevsky Suppose you say "I need a printer `P`". Then I ask you: what do you need the printer for? You answer: "I have special software and a PDF file that tells me how, given a printer `P`, I can generate a paper artifact `A`" (that is, you have an `P => A`). Then I say to you: "just go to a copyshop, it will take your `P => A`, and print a whole `List[A]`, if you want". That is, a copyshop is of type `(P => A) => List[A]`. Now, notice that you can get what you want (printed artifact `A`),  because a copyshop `(P => A) => List[A]` behaves like a *generalized printer* `P`.